# Batch print loop for pdf

Tags: batch-file

I would like to create a simple batch file that prints all my PDF files ffrom a folder. 
But it seems that within this `FOR` loop I cannot use:

```
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 >nul
taskkill /F /IM AcroRd32.exe
```

Why?

My batch file:

```
:AAA

for %%i in (*.pdf) do (
  "C:\Programme\Adobe\Reader 8.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /t %%i
  ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 >nul
  taskkill /F /IM AcroRd32.exe
)

copy u:\print\*.pdf u:\print\prited_files
del *.pdf
echo wait for next print job
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 30000 >nul

GOTO AAA
```

Comment: Hi, I've taken the liberty to edit your question so that it means SO standards. Please read the [ask] if you want more details on how to ask questions on SO.

Comment: Why do you use ping?  What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Your batch file runs AcroRd32.exe and waits for it to close before continuing to the next line.  So it never runs your ping command.

To run a command in the background, use `start`.  Type `help start` at the command line for more information about the command.

```
start "" "C:\Programme\Adobe\Reader 8.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /t %%i
```